# xamarin installation issue on widows7 , for visual studio 2012 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I am trying to install Xamarin  on my windows 7 system with visual studio 2012 ultimate. But Xamarin for visual studio 2012 is not installing , here I am pasting the stack error details.

> [Info] MSI (s) (14:14) [18:44:55:670]: Product: Xamarin --
>   Installation failed.
>
> [Info] MSI (s) (14:14) [18:44:55:671]: Windows Installer installed the
>   product. Product Name: Xamarin. Product Version: 4.1.2.18. Product
>   Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Xamarin. Installation success or error
>   status: 1603.
>
> [Info] === Logging stopped: 8/3/2016  18:44:55 ===
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.828] [Info] END >>>>>> msiexec log:
>   '\Temp\tmp1B41.tmp'
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.828] [Info] Status: failed.
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Exception] Installation of software item
>   'Xamarin' failed with exception.
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Exception]
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException: Installation of archive
>   '\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.1.2.18.msi'
>   failed with exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: MSI
>   execution failed.
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Exception] at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.InstallMSI(String file, Boolean
>   needsPrivileges, Action`3 processCommandArguments)
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Exception] at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String
>   path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Exception] --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Exception] at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String
>   path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Exception] at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.InstallDownloadedItem(String
>   url, InstallationArchiveHandler handler, DownloadServiceWorkItem
>   download)
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Exception] at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32
>   tryNumber)
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Exception] at
>   Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinVSSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32
>   tryNumber)
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Exception] at
>   WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.829] [Info] Status: failed.
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:55.929] [Debug] Showing manual installation window
>   because of error
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:59.335] [Debug] Starting installation complete task.
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:59.335] [Info] Background installation worker
>   completed.
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:59.536] [Info] Installation completed with failure
>
> [2016-08-03 13:14:59.536] [Info] Status: failed.
>
> [2016-08-03 13:19:42.941] [Debug] Showing manual installation window
>   because of error

Please help me to resolve this, I have tried with all options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the installer as an administrator? It would appear that the `.msi` failed to install as it needed elevated privileges.

If running the installer as an administrator doesn't help, you can try a manual installation. Feel free to reach out to contact@xamarin.com for assistance with this (please add the link to this question in your email) and we can send you the manual installation download links - we are available to help with installation issues.